# Attributes for Class Fields using JaXB

Tags: jaxb, attributes

I am trying to simplify the conversion of POJO to XML, but I am facing issues with Class field attributes.

Consider the following XML files

```
 <cat>
        <displayTexts>
            <displayText language="en">12</displayText>
            <displayText language="en">23</displayText>
        </displayTexts>
    </cat>
```

And

I have a class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "cat")
public class Category{
    List<Integer> list;

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "displayTexts")
    @XmlElement(name = "displayText")
    public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }


}
```

How can I write an adaptor which will produce XML mentioned as above?

Right now it will produce something like below xml ::

```
<cat>
        <displayTexts>
            <displayText>12</displayText>
            <displayText>23</displayText>
        </displayTexts>
    </cat>
```

**Note::**  I am not allowed to use MoXy. And I know I can achieve this by writing a different class. The question is can we write an adaptor so that I can generalize this attribute thing for any class field?

Answer (score 0):

Although I would still recommend, using a class Instead of Integer to use the value for displayText and it's attribute, but still if you want to achieve without any new class, you can give following a shot using @XmlAnyElement for your displayList and "creating" the xml yourself:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

@XmlRootElement(name = "cat")
public class Category {

    List<Integer> list;

    @XmlAnyElement()
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyIntegerAdapter.class)
    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    //@XmlElement(name = "displayText")

    public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Category bx = new Category();

        List<Integer> lists = Arrays.asList(121, 212);
        bx.setList(lists);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Category.class);
        MyIntegerAdapter adapter = new MyIntegerAdapter();
        Marshaller marrshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marrshaller.setAdapter(adapter);
        marrshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        marrshaller.marshal(bx, System.out);
    }
}

class MyIntegerAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Element, List<Integer>> {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public MyIntegerAdapter() {
    }

    private DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilder() throws Exception {
        // Lazy load the DocumentBuilder as it is not used for unmarshalling.
        if (null == documentBuilder) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        return documentBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public Element marshal(List<Integer> lists) throws Exception {
        if (null == lists) {
            return null;
        }
        Document document = getDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element element = document.createElement("displayTexts");
        for (int value : lists) {
            Element displayText = document.createElement("displayText");
            System.out.println("value.." + value);
            displayText.setTextContent(value + "");
            displayText.setAttribute("Lang", "en");
            element.appendChild(displayText);
        }
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> unmarshal(Element v) throws Exception {
        //TODO
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I should better go with creating the separate classes. Appreciate the effort anyway.

Comment: That is a wise decision and better approach @azhar.